# git push doesn't prompt me for a password when invoked from terminator instead of konsole

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, gitlab, terminator

I have a remote git repository on a gitlab server.
I'm accessing the server via ssh. When I type `git push` from a `Konsole`-window, it works perfectly fine, and git asks me for the passphrase for my ssh-key pair.

I type in my password and the push is performed. When I try doing the same thing from a `Terminator`-window, it doesn't work. Instead Terminator outputs

```
Enter passphrase for key '/example/directory/user/.ssh/id_rsa':   
git@example-git.examplecompany.de's password:  
Permission denied, please try again.  
git@example-git.examplecompany.de's password:    
Permission denied, please try again.  
git@example-git.examplecompany.de's password:    
Permission denied (publickey,password).  
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

without ever asking me to input my passphrase. How can I change this behaviour?

Comment: Is it asking you for your passphrase or git password?

Comment: @CodeWizard Oh sorry, forgot to mention. It's asking me for the password for my gitlab account.

Answer (score 0):

In this case when you mentioned that its asking for your GitLab account it means that if your password is accurate so your ssh key is not set properly.

copy your key to your GitLab account and try again.

```
# grab the key
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think, you missunderstood my question. The problem is, that Terminator doesn't even ask me for my password. It automatically outputs "permission denied" without giving me the chance to enter the password. I'm pretty sure, that my ssh key is set properly since everything is working perfectly fine on Konsole. The problem is only with terminator.

Comment: It means that you have it in credential manage somewhere. can you create new keys and replace the old ones?

Comment: Okay, sorry I have to correct everything that I said before. I thought that Konsole/Terminator were prompting me for my gitlab-password, but that was not correct. It's actually prompting me for the passphrase of my ssh-key pair. They just happened to be the same which is why I thought, it was prompting for the gitlab password.